# The minimum number of non-coplanar vectors whose sum can be zero

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

I don't know why but

#### The answer is 4

But according to me it should be 3. Why is "3" wrong?

Comment: three vectors form a triangle which is planar?

Comment: Hi! Could you please elaborate on why you think it should be 3? Thanks!

Comment: because if we keep two vectors making an acute angle and then take out their resultant then placing the third vector in the resultant's opposite direction which has the same magnitude as the resultant  it will give us a 0. So in this way three vectors will give a sum of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any two non-parallel vectors *w* and *x* will be co-planar (and will define a plane **WX**). So if you have three non-coplanar vectors *w*, *x*, and *y* then necessarily there will be a component of the vector *y* that is out of the plane **WX** - i.e. normal to **WX**. (If that was not the case then *y* would have to be co-planar with *w* and *x*.) But neither *w* or *x* can have a component that isn't in the **WX** plane (as they are co-planar to it), so in order to cancel the part of *y* that is normal to **WX**, you will need yet another vector *z* that also has a component normal to **WX**. So at least four non co-planar vectors are needed to sum to zero. To show that four is sufficient just consider the vectors (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (-1,-1,-1), which are not co-planar and sum to zero.